How to add external library to C/C++ JNI project via CMake
I have an Android-C library project that I am working on in Android Studio. I need to add external libraries like C directly to my project (not via Android Studio Gradle Dependency).
I have installed OpenSSL 3 via homebrew and set OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR in my .zprofile. However, when I attempt to build the project, I'm faced with the following errors

C++ build system [configure] failed while executing:
    /opt/homebrew/bin/cmake \
      -H/Users/mba/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/src/main/cpp \
      -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android \
      -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON \
      -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=24 \
      -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-24 \
      -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a \
      -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=arm64-v8a \
      -DANDROID_NDK=/Users/mba/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393 \
      -DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=/Users/mba/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393 \
      -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/Users/mba/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake \
      -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/Users/mba/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.22.1/bin/ninja \
      -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/Users/mba/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/444d406q/obj/arm64-v8a \
      -DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/Users/mba/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/444d406q/obj/arm64-v8a \
      -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug \
      -DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=/Users/mba/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/.cxx/Debug/444d406q/prefab/arm64-v8a/prefab \
      -B/Users/mba/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/.cxx/Debug/444d406q/arm64-v8a \
      -GNinja \
      -DANDROID_STL=c++_shared
  from /Users/mba/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app
CMake Error at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.29.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
  system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY
  OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)

My CMakeLists.txt
# For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html.
# For more examples on how to use CMake, see https://github.com/android/ndk-samples.

# Sets the minimum CMake version required for this project.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.1)

project("nfcNative")

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "OPENSSL_LIBRARIES:${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}")

add_library(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} SHARED
        nfcNative.c
        commands.c
        rsa.c
        )

include_directories(src/main/cpp/include/ ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
        android
        log
        OpenSSL::Crypto
        OpenSSL::Ssl
        )


I set OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR in the following locations and the compiler still can't find it

Also, I am able to find package added via Android studio dependency with
find_package(openssl REQUIRED CONFIG)

however, the provided package (com.android.ndk.thirdparty:openssl:1.1.1q-beta-1  is only version 1.1.1 and my project requires the more recent versions 3.x

You cannot take libraries compiled for macOS and expect them to work on Android..

Consider using the published OpenSSL ndkPorts

Put prebuilt library files in src/main/jniLibs/[abi] as stated in here. After that, you can use find_library and target_link_libraries to link it.
Prebulit latest version of OpenSSL is archived here. Note that this archive provides static version.

That repository uses an ancient version of the NDK and compiler. OP is better off following the official build instructions

Homebrew installs libraries compiled for host platform (macOS), while you need libraries compiled for Android.
You need to compile OpenSSL for Android:
https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/NOTES-ANDROID.md
